# [Android]Alertdialog return boolean onclick

Tags: android, function, dialog, return, alert

I have a problem with a AlertDialog : I'ld like that my AlertDialog return true if the user click on Positive button and false if he click on negative button. The function must block the program until the user click on a button.

My code :

```
public static boolean errorMD5(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error));
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.errorMD5);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //The function return true
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               //The function return false                    
            }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity you should implement 2 functions.

```
 onYesPressed() and onNoPressed()
```

and call them from your dialog.

Or you can implement just a function that takes a boolean parameter

```
    onUserDismissDialog(boolean allow)
```

and call this function from your dialog OnClickListener.

Comment: No, it doesn't work I can't call a function in my activity in this function (the function is in another class)

Comment: You need to call MyActivity.this.onUserDismissDialog(true) .